# Looking for design help on how generate tree structure dynamically

Tags: java, android

I am looking here for a good design approach to start with so I don't end up on the wrong path. Basically, in my app I need to come with a series of questions that are dependent on each other answer. For example if I answer Q1 with Yes it takes me Q2 but if I answer No it takes me to Q3. Same thing for the later questions and so on until I display the final result to the user. Think of it like a Tree thing (where the possible answers are not limited to yes/no, it could be yes/no/maybe)

The immidiate thing that comes to mind is to hard code all the paths. However a change maybe expensive for this ifI decide to change the paths.

The other option I have in mind is have my App reads a JSON file which has all the questions, answers and linkages. My code would then parse that and establish the paths.

Is there another recommended way of doing the above? Or perhaps somehow not re-invent the wheel?  A help or pointer is appreciated

Thank you so much

Comment: What about using indexes to point to questions, like a neural network structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a tree but you don't have to use a tree to model it. What I would do in your case is to define a dependency list of each of the questions. For example, Q2 depends on A1=yes (A1 to mean answer to Q1).

If you can encode the dependency together with your question in some data structure outside your code, then it would be easy for your code to read in that dependency and dynamically decide whether or not to show a particular question.

Comment: So would the data structure be in JSON for example? Or Excel? Or is there maybe a tool for that?

Comment: Don't know if there is a tool specially designed for that. I am talking only from a high level point of view. Using json or any other structural data format is always possible and it should depend on other perspectives, such as the platform you target, development environment and skill sets etc.

Comment: I am targeting Java. I want basically to establish questions structure. For example, if you answer Y to Q1 then you you go to Q2 but if you say N then you go to Q3 and so on.  I want to give my client a specific format to write the questions/answers and I would just read this file in my Java and create the process for them. The only thing I can think of is come up with JSON schema for them. Any other ideas?